# What's a reasonably secure way to store credentials at rest for use in a screen scraping application?

Tags: node.js, security, phantomjs, casperjs

By virtue of PhantomJS, CasperJS allows you to specify a JSON file to load when the application starts. I have my credentials stored in this file, which is a little better than having it hardcoded in the source file:

```
var json = require('testfile.json');

var username = json['username'];
var mykey = json['mykey'];
```

I still have my credentials stored in plain text on the server, which I'd like to get far away from. This process will be automated, so I can't pass in the credentials via command line arguments each time it runs, nor do I want to store the arguments in Windows Task Scheduler. What's a secure way to store this information at rest?

Comment: It's not secure, in a strict sense, but what about storing the information as an environment variable? The values would still be available in the registry, but that's a bit better than having them in a text file.

Answer (score 1):

Using the functions listed on this page:http://lollyrock.com/articles/nodejs-encryption/

I was able to build the following proof of concept for my own needs:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var algorithm = 'aes256';
var password = 'correcthorsestaplebattery';
var string = "Something I\'d like to encrypt, like maybe login credentials for a site I need to                 scrape.";

console.log('\n\nText: ' + string);

var encrypted = encrypt(new Buffer(string, "utf8"), algorithm, password);

console.log('\n\nEncrypted: ' + encrypted);

var decrypted = decrypt(encrypted, algorithm, password).toString('utf8');

console.log('\n\nDecrypted: ' + decrypted);

// check to prove 2-way encryption works
console.log('\n\nAre they the same before and after crypto? ');
console.log(decrypted == string);


function encrypt(buffer, algorithm, password){
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm,password)
    var crypted = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(buffer),cipher.final()]);
    return crypted;
}

function decrypt(buffer, algorithm, password){
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm,password)
    var dec = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(buffer) , decipher.final()]);
    return dec;
}
```

This uses AES256, which should be as secure as 2-way encryption can be, although I'm not advanced enough to comment on the implementation. It's better than plain text anyway.

From this, you could easily write the output to a file instead of the console as shown. As long as you're just parsing a file containing JSON, you would just have to add the step of decrypting before interpreting it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is not applicable to pure PhantomJS because it has a runtime distinct from node.js and does not have a crypto module. Although, PhantomJS can be run through a bridge from node.js. The other thing is, would this really be better in contrast to plain credentials? If the key/password is somewhere on the drive, then this is just a fancy way to obfuscate. If indeed a bridge is used to run PhantomJS, it is likely that the credentials can be sniffed from the network interface, because a bridge handles communication through the network.

Comment: I was saying that it was better because it at least obfuscates. I was only trying to demonstrate how to make the encryption work though; I prompt the user for the key/password for encryption. This would solve his problem because the credential decryption could be run in it's own minimal process, returning the decrypted info when needed. That doesn't solve the sniffing issue though, which could be fatal depending on how sensitive the information is. I would argue that with that vulnerability it is still safer than using plain text because even unskilled people could access those credentials.